# Linq to Sql - returning IEnumerable without using Lists

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, ienumerable, iqueryable

I'm wanting to write a function using Linq to Sql that will return an `IEnumerable<TEntity>`, in such a way that the results are truly enumerated from the database as they are consumed.

The wrong way to do this is:

```
IEnumerable<TEntity> GetResults()
{
    using (var dbContext = new DataContext())
        return dbContext.TEntitys;
}
```

This throws an exception when you try to enumerate the results, because the connection closes as soon as the method returns and leaves the `using` block.

Another way to do it is to use a List to crystallize the results, and then enumerate over the list, but this does not do the enumeration from the server as it's consumed.

```
IEnumerable<TEntity> GetResults()
{
    using (var dbContext = new DataContext())
        return dbContext.TEntitys.ToList();
}
```

But I've just realized that you can just `yield` the results, which will keep the connection open until all the results have been enumerated:

```
IEnumerable<TEntity> GetResults()
{
    using (var dbContext = new DataContext())
    {
        foreach (var e in dbContext.TEntities)
            yield return e;
    }
}
```

Is it bad to do it this way? I tried searching for answers or blog posts that consider this way of doing it, but wasn't able to find any, but at the same time I'd doubt that it's revolutionary.

Comment: From what I remember of LINQ to SQL, you don't actually need to dispose of the `DataContext` anyway... so that would be a simpler approach.

Comment: Pass in the context either though your constructor or a parameter and return IQueryable instead

Comment: @JonSkeet If I just initialize the `DataContext` without the `using` block, will it stay open until I've finished enumerating the results, and will it definitely close properly?

Comment: @MatthewWhited I've heard that you shouldn't pass `IQueryable`s around outside of a Repository Pattern, though it certainly would help with further filtering the result set.

Comment: @ZacFaragher: IIRC, LINQ to SQL is smart in terms of when it closes connections etc. But you should basically do more research into it - I know there are articles out there.

Comment: @JonSkeet Looks like you already had the answer [here](http://csharpindepth.com/ViewNote.aspx?NoteID=89), thanks!

Comment: You'll hear a lot of things while programming.  Most of it is bad advice.  It's your choice but you totally defeats the purpose of `IQueryable` if you make it `IEnumerable` or `List` instead of passing it up the stack.